# Object Time(2014, 2, 17 11:02:08, 2014-03-17 11, 02, 08) has no method 'getTimezoneOffset

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, datetime, google-visualization

Working on a google chart which are getting data from phpmyadmin. I am having a problem with time/date formatting: Object Time(2014, 2, 17 11:02:08, 2014-03-17 11, 02, 08) has no method 'getTimezoneOffset.

My database:

[image]

Code:

```
    <?php

    $con=mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die("Failed to connect with database!!!!");
    mysql_select_db("chart", $con);

    $sth = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM googlechart");

    $rows = array();
    //flag is not needed
    $flag = true;
    $table = array();

    $table['cols'] = array(

    array('label' => 'Time', 'type' => 'datetime'),
    array('label' => 'PH',      'type' => 'number'),
    array('label' => 'temperature','type' => 'number'), 
    array('label' => 'Chlorine','type' => 'number'),
    );

    $rows = array();

    while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($sth)) {

    // assumes dates are in the format "yyyy-MM-dd"
    $dateString = $r['Time'];
    $dateArray = explode('-', $dateString);
    $year = $dateArray[0];
    $month = $dateArray[1] - 1; // subtract 1 to convert to javascript's 0-indexed months
    $day = $dateArray[2];

    // assumes time is in the format "hh:mm:ss"
    $timeString = $r['Time'];
    $timeArray = explode(':', $timeString);
    $hours = $timeArray[0];
    $minutes = $timeArray[1];
    $seconds = $timeArray[2];

    $temp = array();
    $temp[] = array('v' => "Time($year, $month, $day, $hours, $minutes, $seconds)"); 
    $temp[] = array('v' => (string) $r['PH']);
    $temp[] = array('v' => (string) $r['temperature']);
    $temp[] = array('v' => (string) $r['Chlorine']);

    $rows[] = array('c' => $temp);

    }

    $table['rows'] = $rows;
    $jsonTable = json_encode($table);
    /* echo $jsonTable; */  

?>
```

Html/javascript code:

```
   google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

      function drawChart() {
        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(<?=$jsonTable?>);



        var options = {
        /*width: 900, height: 900, */
          title: 'Visualization',
          curveType: 'function', 
           legend: { position: 'bottom' },
           pointSize: 12,
        vAxis: {title: "Values", titleTextStyle: {italic: false}},
        hAxis: {title: "Time", titleTextStyle: {italic: false}},
        explorer: { 
                actions: ['dragToZoom', 'rightClickToReset'], 
                axis: 'vertical'
            }


        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
        chart.draw(data, options);


      }
```

Comment: It would be more helpful if you made a simplified version that throwed the same error with static data, and without PHP

Comment: I think i see the problem, but not how to solve it: https://www.dropbox.com/s/zzg6ch475a9cufb/verdi.png

Comment: That's the error, not the problem :|

Comment: I see! :/ Where do you think the problem is ?

Comment: There is no call to a method `getTimezoneOffset` in the code you have shown us.

Comment: How do I use getTimezoneOffset and where in the code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What this is doing...

```
$dateString = $r['Time'];
$dateArray = explode('-', $dateString);
```

...is chunking up your time:

```
2014-03-17 11:02:08
```

...into:

```
'2014'
'03'
'17 11:02:08'
```

..where the last item is not what you want for `$day`.

Similarly,

```
$timeArray = explode(':', $timeString);
```

...is chunking into:

```
'2014-03-17 11'
'02'
'08'
```

...where the first item is not what you want for hours.

More seriously, however, I'm not sure whether:

```
$temp[] = array('v' => "Time($year, $month, $day, $hours, $minutes, $seconds)");
```

...which will merely build a string, will be accepted by [Google's DataTable constructor](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#dataparam), as it appears not.

While you have the right idea in building a JSON object to get a useful format over to JavaScript, JSON regrettably does not support dates, so I believe once you obtain the days and hours on the PHP side, you will need to iterate through the table on the JavaScript side to convert those strings into `Date()` objects rather than the `Time(...)` string you have built.

Comment: I would probably use `preg_match` to make things easier to get only what you want out of it.

Comment: I see, i am new to that. Could you please show how that will be done in my code ? Thank you very much for taking your time.

Comment: Something like `preg_match("@\\d\\d-\\d\\d-\\d\\d@", $str, $matches)`. See the docs at http://php.net/preg_match or open a new question which isolates the problem; StackOverflow is intended for helping with individual, isolated problems, one at a time. Also, FYI, I have updated my answer to indicate another potentially more serious problem you might encounter.

Comment: I saw that problem also, I got help on the code from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22461062/google-chart-date-and-time-from-database/22466967?noredirect=1#22466967 AND another help from here: http://jsbin.com/vahuvexi/1/edit  But iam very stuck right now actually, since i am novice in coding.

Comment: That answer uses `Date()` not `Time()`. Perhaps you should try that once you figure out the parsing of the date. But again, start a new question, as it is otherwise not fair to people here who take the time to identify your main issue, to have to go through more hoops to help write all of the code for you.

Comment: Also, that person's answer was based on your Date and Time being in separate columns.

Comment: I saw that and corrected that. Sorry, my bad. I will make a new question with the new problem I get now.

Comment: New question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22476299/all-series-on-a-given-axis-must-be-of-the-same-data-type

Comment: And don't repeat all of the same info all over again in your new question. Just ask the part you need help with, e.g., how do I get the date out of this string. If a demo can be done in JS, then provide a Fiddle or the like. And if those of us answering your previous questions have provided an answer which correctly addresses the question you asked, don't forget to mark one answer as correct for each question (or leave comments until you are clear on whether the answer provided actually addresses your question).

Comment: Thanks, sorry. I am new to stackoverflow, so really thanks for the help. But one day I will surely be good as you. Do you have any idea how to solve my problem ? I thank for all the time you take for helping.

Comment: We all learn by doing, and I wasn't objecting to your seeking for full help here--I was merely indicating how to shape your questions in the interests of those here and to suggest to you indirectly that it takes time to learn, and you should expect even simple programs to take an inordinate amount of time if you don't first focus on learning the basics. For example, for PHP, read the docs on `explode` and all the string functions or read a tutorial which covers most of the string functions. Glad to see from your other issues that you found enough help to resolve your problem here though.

Comment: Thanks, problem was easy solved by: array('label' => 'Date & Time', 'type' => 'datetime'),